# Execute code before http observable starts network call

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular-httpclient

How do you write some code before an angular http client observable makes a network call but after the actual function gets called? The following is the angular http service call

```
this.geocodeApi.getAddressSuggestions(address).subscribe(resp => {..});
```

but how would we do something like

```
this.geocodeApi.getAddressSuggestions(address).before({CODE HERE}).subscribe(resp => {..});
```

Comment: `{CODE HERE}; this.geocodeApi.getAddressSuggestions(address).subscribe(...)`?

Comment: Are you looking for an interceptor? https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: Kind of, but just a one time interceptor for this particular call

Comment: I guess you want to do something like showing loading indicator before the request is issued, right?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do?
If you want to change request before send it, you should use interceptor, like  GSSwain say.
Of course you can use interceptor only when `geocodeApi` use `HttpClient` service.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but...

```
this.sub$ = defer(() => {

  console.log('about to subscribe')

  return this.api('/users/')
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => console.log('complete'))
    );
});
```

What `defer()` will do is not execute the code until it is subscribed, the return is the observable but the outer code will be executed, you can use finalize to clean up.